# ToUnicodeEx not printing "Greater Than"

Tags: c++, windows, input, unicode, keyboard

I wrote a function which processes the user keyboard in order to write text in an app.

In order to do that I use the **ToUnicodeEx** function which uses an array of Key states.
The function is working perfectly fine for every possible input, except for one : I cannot display the ">" sign, which is supposed to be the combination of "SHIFT + <" : it displays the "<" sign instead, as if the SHIFT key was not pressed, whereas it knows it it pressed.

Has somebody already experienced the same and knows what the problem is?

You will find my function code below :

```
    void MyFunction(bool bCapsLockDown)
    {
        IOClass io = GetMyIOInstance();
        HKL layout = GetKeyboardLayout( 0 );
        uchar uKeyboardState[256];
        WCHAR oBuffer[5] = {};

        //Initialization of KeyBoardState
        for (uint i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
             uKeyBoardState[i] = 0;
        }

        // Use of my ConsultKeyState to get the status of pressed keys
        if ( ConsultKeyState( VK_SHIFT ) || bCapsLockDown )
        {
            uKeyboardState[VK_CAPITAL] = 0xff;
        }
        if ( ConsultKeyState( VK_CONTROL ) )
        {
            uKeyboardState[VK_CONTROL] = 0xff;
        }
        if ( ConsultKeyState( VK_MENU ) )
        {
            uKeyboardState[VK_MENU] = 0xff;
        }
        if ( ConsultKeyState( VK_RMENU ) )
        {
            uKeyboardState[VK_MENU] = 0xff;
            uKeyboardState[VK_CONTROL] = 0xff;
        }

        for ( uint iVK = 0; iVK < 256; ++iVK )
        {
            bool bKeyDown = ConsultKeyState( iVK ) != 0;
            uint iSC = MapVirtualKeyEx( iVK, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, layout );

            bool bKeyAlreadyDown = io.KeysDown[iVK];

            io.KeysDown[iVK] = bKeyDown;

            if ( io.KeysDown[iVK] && bKeyAlreadyDown == false )
            {
                int iRet = ToUnicodeEx( iVK, iSC, uKeyboardState, (LPWSTR)oBuffer, 4, 0, layout );
                if( iRet > 0 && (iswgraph( (unsigned short) oBuffer[0] ) || oBuffer[0] == ' ') )
                    io.AddInputCharacter( (unsigned short) oBuffer[0] );
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit :** 
To summarize, my question is : 
What would be the good combination VirtualKey + KeyBoardState to get a ">" displayed?

Comment: @HansPassant The "MAJ" information is contained in the uKeyBoardState! ToUnicodeEx uses it to know if other keys are pressed, as MAJ, ALT, CTRL...

Comment: Best to avoid French on an English website, we say "shift" around here.  The GetKeyboardState() is very strange, you'll retrieve the buffered keyboard state of your own process.  If you don't otherwise pump a message loop then it gets never updated.  Looks like you patched around that problem by using GetAsyncKeyState() but that isn't correct either since that doesn't necessarily match the keyboard state of the process you are trying to poke.  Using UI Automation is always best to sail around trouble like this.

Comment: Oups sorry about Shift, going to edit that right away

Comment: @HansPassant Are you saying that with GetAsyncKeyState I may be retrieving Inputs that are not meant to be for the app? How can I get the updated KeyBoardState otherwise?

Comment: It requires SetWindowsHookEx() to set a WH_KEYBOARD.  Programmers tend to get pretty ticked-off when I mention that.  Deservedly :)

Comment: I edited the question in order to get answers related to the ">" not displaying problem

Comment: I suspect that your issue is that shift and caps lock are not the same thing.  If you want to emulate the pressing of the shift key, you need to set the VK_SHIFT index in uKeyboardState, not VK_CAPITAL.

Comment: The caps lock key only effects letter keys (a '1' is a '1' whether caps is on or not).  The shift key effects pretty much all keys.

Comment: It should be VK_OEM_102 for < and VK_OEM_102 + VK_SHIFT for > at least for a standard french keybord layout.

Comment: Indeed, I realized my mistake (VK_CAPITAL instead of VK_SHIFT) just after adding the bounty. Weird thing is VK_CAPITAL works for EVERY other key on my french keyboard, but this one. @PeterBrittain can you post an answer so I can award the bounty?

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the answer.  Please let me know if you think there's anything I can more usefully add...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `shift` and `caps lock` do not have the same effect on a keyboard.  For example, (on a UK keyboard) pressing `shift+1` = `!`, but pressing `1` with caps lock on still give you `1`.

Your code currently treats them the same, though, and it is using `VK_CAPITAL` in both cases.  This will give you the same effect as if caps lock were on, which is not what you want in this case.

The solution is therefore to break out your logic and use `VK_SHIFT` when you really want shift to be pressed and `VK_CAPITAL` when you want caps lock to be active.